# How can I add my jar file to automatic imports for Scala language in beaker-notebook?

Tags: beaker-notebook

I want to add my Scala internal library jar file in  beaker-notebook Scala language so each time the user creates a new notebook, our library is configured to be automatically imported. Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your jar files in Language Manager under `Class path (jar files, one per line)` box.